# Are multiple forms on a single page supported in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-3.5

I just wanted to confirm if this was true or not - I remember reading somewhere that it was now possible, but after an hour of googling I can't find any definitive proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET WebForms you cannot use multiple forms as it uses a single form model.

In ASP.NET MVC you can.

Comment: This is an interesting scenario, can you provide some links etc. as regards implementation details and reasoning? I'd be very interested in researching this issue some more. Cheers. Granted I should probably google it :-) but if you have further infos ......

Comment: This article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx#S3 talks about the reasoning with regards to how the postback model works. There ways to work around this but if you really need to get around it that bad I would switch to MVC or rethink your design.