# How to submit data twice on an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage.  At the top is a search bar that is inside a `<form id="form1" runat="server">`.

I also want to add a form on that same page that would allow users to register their details.  Problem, ASP.NET only allows one form per page.

How can I achieve my goal?  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you want to be called in different button click events.  Therefore, if the search button is clicked, only the code in the search buttons click event is run.  If the register button is clicked, only the code in the registers click event is run.

Here is an example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Common code

}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Search code

}

protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Register code

}
```

Double clicking the buttons in the designer will create the click events in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one **server side** form on a page.

If it is an option, you can have a client side form (without `runat="server") with a separate action - this POST can go to a different page, where you will have to access`Request.Form` to retrieve the values posted.

Another option is to use separate buttons for posting with different event handlers.

Comment: thanks for reminding me on my last answer. I really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple HTML form approach but there is the problem of always post the whole page back. or use mvc:

[Are multiple forms on a single page supported in asp.net 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504209/are-multiple-forms-on-a-single-page-supported-in-asp-net-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the answer by @Simon, it's easy to have multiple click handlers in your code-behind to process exactly what you need on the page - this is the easiest way to solve the "lack of multiple forms" issue.

Something very useful in this situation is the `DefaultButton` attribute of the `<asp:Panel>` control.  This means that should you have multiple areas of your page with (for instance) `<asp:TextBox>` controls, and each of those areas has a specific `<asp:Button>` associated, if the focus is in one of the textboxes then pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> will result in the `DefaultButton` being clicked.

For example...

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
  Search: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSearcn"/>
  <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSearch" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

[See MSDN for more information on the `DefaultButton` attribute of `<asp:Panel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx)